# React change value inside the element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a react element like this:

```
var element = 
<div> 
    <span>37</span> 
    <span>increased</span>
<div>
```

I want to modify this element by add "activities" after 37, so it becomes:

```
var element = 
<div> 
    <span>37 Activities</span> 
    <span>increased</span>
<div>
```

I am stucked on how to change this element. Is there a way to "inject" the string Activities to the element?

Note: I don't have access the the function which returns the `element`. What I can do is to modify the `element`.

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't have access to the function that returns element? Another way would be to `cloneElement` and iterate through children nodes until you reach the correct node, but it would be a pain for nothing.

Comment: Most probably, there are some element that is receiving `37` as property. Just change it to `37 Activities`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is a bit unclear. As far as I understand, you want to add the `string` **Activities** in the `span` tag after `37`. I have added a way to achieve this using vanilla javascript. Get all the span tags on the page and do the manipulation.

[Solution - online IDE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ivrsrz?file=src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  var element = (
   <div> 
    <span>37 </span> 
    <span>increased</span>
   </div>
  )
  const add = () => {
    document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML += 'Activities';
  }
 return (
   <div>
    {element}
    <button onClick={() => add()}> Add</button>
  </div>
 );
}
```

Hope this solution helps!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the element is returned by the other component. I can't change it by adding `{str}`. If I can add `{str}`, I can just add the string `Activities`. I am wondering if I can use some operations to modify it.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to be a full, stand-alone answer with code that doesn't depend on links?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Added!